# How to extend logical volume swap space to atleast 64 GB on SSD

Tags: server, ssd, swap, lvm

My current configuration of physical volumes is as follows.

```
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda5
  VG Name               vgssd
  PV Size               190.89 GiB / not usable 1.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              48867
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          48867
  PV UUID               SaJLLb-KpaE-ZeyS-k5HR-eNQ6-A1tp-zpZjUe

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb
  VG Name               vgssd
  PV Size               465.76 GiB / not usable 4.02 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              119234
  Free PE               194
  Allocated PE          119040
  PV UUID               yekbZZ-guPE-6Gjh-qJux-MjMi-RHYx-YevZop
```

And below is the configuration of my logical volumes:

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/vgssd/home
  VG Name                vgssd
  LV UUID                XozHK8-4dJ2-XfQE-7f2J-xGLB-2nVg-rO9yA3
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                4.66 GiB
  Current LE             1192
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/vgssd/swp
  VG Name                vgssd
  LV UUID                CyYT1b-BQhM-vwQa-W8oU-0E8Y-OVYD-894T86
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                1.86 GiB
  Current LE             476
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/vgssd/srv
  VG Name                vgssd
  LV UUID                aIwCXs-ibKG-5IUl-rxI1-UZJT-fypS-xpHyKC
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                649.37 GiB
  Current LE             166239
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:2
```

Currently, I want to extend the swap space ( `/dev/vgssd/swp` ) from ~2 GB to 64 GB. I think I can shrink `/dev/vgssd/srv` and save 64 GB for swap space. However, I am not sure which physical volumes ( `/dev/sda5` or `/dev/sdb` ) the new swap space is allocated to when I actually extend ( `/dev/vgssd/swp` ).

I want to make sure the swap space is on ( SSD with PV name `/dev/sda5` ) so data can be written and read in high speed.

Do you have any ideas how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

The *lvextend* command accepts physical devices as argument :

```
lvextend -L 64000 /dev/vgssd/swp /dev/sda5
```

Will allocate all the new extends on /dev/sda5